# Shade of background colour, underline and uppercase text when creating a button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a standard button. I'm having few issues completing this. Below is my scss

How do I disable the text underline after the button is clicked and Why won't the text convert to uppercase when `text-transform: uppercase;` is used?

```
$btCol: #ff6600;

.Btn {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid $btCol;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase; //why won't convert the text to uppercase?
}
.Btn:hover {
    background-color: lighten($btCol, 50%);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.Btn:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
.Btn:disabled {
    background-color: #eb675e;
    color: #999;
}
```

**EDIT:**

html:

```
<a href="#" class="Btn">light red</a>
```

Comment: You should split this into multiple questions. You will be more likely to find an answer if you do. Also, please post any applicable HTML.

Comment: You have 2 completely unrelated questions here, ask 1 at a time.  Also, this is not a Sass problem, only post the compiled CSS.

Comment: @jsve: thanks. :) I presume all answers would be a single line? So I asked them together. I've added the HTML.

Comment: @cimmanon: thanks ok, I've removed sass

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://sassmeister.com/gist/94ce4b0d3e22ab8fd3f5

Comment: @cimmanon thanks. :) Can you show how to get `background-color: lighten($btCol, 75%);` to work?

Comment: @Beki Fact is,  You've probably lightened it too much,,,it's not clear what you want exactly but 50% seems like a lot - http://sassmeister.com/gist/8704f854f6308aae393f

Answer (score -2):

Instead of trying to apply every style to an anchor tag you could try to create an actual button. This would also make it more semantic. I created a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/5m6b0dzq/3/

The markup:

```
<button class="Btn"><a href="#">Light Red</a></button>
```

The CSS:

```
.Btn {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:5px 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase; //why won't convert the text to uppercase?
}

.Btn a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.Btn:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
.Btn:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```